# Closed form of the integral $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}{x} \tan^{-1}{\frac{x}{2}} \tan^{-1}{\frac{x}{3}}}{x^2+1} \, \text{d}x$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals

This integral was found on a dead forum so I cannot obtain any further information on it.

$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}{x} \tan^{-1}{\frac{x}{2}} \tan^{-1}{\frac{x}{3}}}{x^2+1} \, \text{d}x$$

I could not find a closed form using ISC++

The equivalent form

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \theta \tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{\tan{\theta}}{2}\right)} \tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{\tan{\theta}}{3}\right)} \, \text{d}x$$

does not seem any more promising.

Perhaps a carefully considered contour could solve this problem but I do not have enough familiarity with complex analysis to come up with an argument.

Comment: Paging @Cleo $\mbox{}$

Comment: That looks so horrendous that you should have let it rest in peace in that forum...

Comment: Have you been able to find any identities that relate $\arctan(x)$ to $\arctan\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$?

Comment: @DonAntonio I guess that's why they call it Morbid Curiousity... :P

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source of the problem, its motivation,  your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. Posts that merely state a problem are discouraged on this site.

Comment: If you know how to compute $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(ax)}{1+x^2}\,dx$ by differentiation under the integral sign, you just have to apply a partial fraction decomposition to compute $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2 x^2)(1+b^2 x^2)(1+c^2 x^2)}\,dx $$ then integrate such thing over the proper parallelepiped in $da\,db\,dc$ to get a nasty combination of dilogarithms. It is not difficult, it is just boring and more suited for a CAS.

Comment: For instance $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)\arctan(x/2)}{1+x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi^3}{24}-\frac{\pi}{4}\log^2(2)+\frac{\pi}{8}\log^2(3)-\frac{\pi}{8}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right).$$

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)\arctan(x/2)}{1+x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi^3}{24}-\frac{\pi}{4}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$

Comment: I don't think only dilogarithms have to be considered. $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ ("degree 2") and probably the "degree" of requested integral is 4. (the "degree" of the one above is 3). $\text{Li}_4()$ is expected or anything of "degree" 4 (as $G^2$ for example)

Comment: @FDP: you are right, I should have said *poly*logarithms before.